# What philosophy question did John Galt ask?

Tags: ayn-rand, atlas-shrugged

Hugh Akston stated that, when he first met John Galt, John asked a question on Plato's metaphysics that he would've been proud to get from someone who had studied philosophy for six years, a question that Plato didn't have the sense to ask himself. What was the question (or what might it have been)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the book ever answers what the question was, so I'd like to take a shot at your more subjective question:

> what might it have been?

There's a question that is asked a number of times throughout the book by the heroes:

**"By what right?"**

A few examples:

> What motive moved them?—what was their knowledge?—which one of them,
> unaided, could bring a chunk of ore out of the earth? . . . Destroyed
> at the whim of men whom he had never seen and who had never seen those
> tiers of metal . . . Destroyed, because they so decided. By what
> right?

> "Dagny, by what right?” Eddie Willers had asked her, his voice quiet,
> but the words sounding like a cry. "By what right are they all doing
> it?

> You, who've kept them all alive, have been called an exploiter. You,
> the purest and most moral man among them, have been sneered at as a
> 'vulgar materialist.' Have you stopped to ask them: by what right?—by
> what code?—by what standard?

So I believe it's plausible that Galt may have asked *By what right?* when he began to see the world taken over by looters and began to see men of the mind suffocated by pull peddlers.